# Send only one e-mail with different recipients in foreach using PHP and maintaining the whole code

Tags: php, phpmailer, google-dfp

I'm facing a little issue when I'm trying to send only one e-mail using some datas from a foreach loop. When I echo the data inside foreach, all code works, but making this, the code sends a lot of e-mails.

When I put the code responsible for sending mail outside this foreach, only one e-mail is sent. Ignoring my conditions in the foreach, I echo the keys, and they bring me the last key.

I want to send one e-mail containing the two conditions I wrote in the foreach: if from atendimento I want to send all data from atendimento 1596649 to one recipient and 1596652 data to other recipient.

I'm using Windows 10, MySQL 5, PHP 5 and apache 2.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dfp_dados WHERE atendimento IS NOT NULL';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$resultado = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql2 = 'SELECT atendimento FROM dfp_dados WHERE atendimento IS NOT NULL';
$result2 = $pdo->query($sql2);
$resultado2 = $result2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$atendmail = '';
$check = false;

foreach ($resultado2 as $key2 => $value2) {

    if($value2['atendimento'] == "1596649"){
        $atendmail = 'email';
    } elseif($value2['atendimento'] == "1596652"){
        $atendmail = 'email2';
    }

    $conteudo = '<table>' .
    '<tr>' .
    '<th>Order Id</th>' .
    '<th>Line Item Id</th>' .
    '<th>Campanha</th>' .
    '<th>Formato</th>' .
    '<th>Data de Início</th>' .
    '<th>Data de Término</th>' .
    '<th>Total de Dias</th>' .
    '<th>Dias Veiculados</th>' .
    '<th>Impressões Programadas</th>' .
    '<th>Impressões Projetadas</th>' .
    '<th>Impressões Entregues</th>' .
    '<th>Impressões Faltantes</th>' .
    '<th>Cliques</th>' .
    '<th>CTR</th>' .
    '<th>Resultado Final</th>' .
    '<th>Under/Over</th>'.
    '</tr>';

    foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
        $array = array_merge_recursive($value, $value2);

        if($array['atendimento'][0] == $array['atendimento'][1]){
            $conteudo .= '<tr>'.
            '<td>'.$value['orderId'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['lineItemId'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['campanha'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['formato'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['dataInicio'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['dataFim'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['totalDias'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['diasVeiculados'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['impressoesProgramadas'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['impressoesProjetadas'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['impressoesEntregues'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['impressoesFaltantes'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['cliques'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['ctr'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['resultadoFinal'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$value['underOver'].'</td>'.
            '</tr>';
        }
    }
    $conteudo .= '</table>';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'myUsername';
    $mail->Password = 'myPass';
    $mail->setFrom('opec@webedia-group.com');
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
    $mail->addAddress($atendmail);
    $mail->Subject = 'Suas Campanhas no DFP';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $conteudo;

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Erro no envio do email: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Envio OK!';
    }
}
echo $conteudo;
```

Comment: if you put  $atendmail = $value['toemail'] inside foreach it should work

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i don't have this key in my MySQL, the e-mail was declarated in the first foreach

Comment: Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SELECT` query so you only fetch the rows for those two recipients.

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT atendimento FROM dfp_dados WHERE atendimento IN (1596649, 1596652)';
```

Or you could change the `foreach` loop so you don't send mails for anyone else.

```
if($value2['atendimento'] == "1596649"){
    $atendmail = 'email';
} elseif($value2['atendimento'] == "1596652"){
    $atendmail = 'email2';
} else {
    continue; // skip the rest of this loop iteration
}
```